# How to determine forward/backward direction of a netflow

Tags: networking, wireshark

Suppose I have the information of

```
SourceIP, DestinationIP, SourcePort, DestinationPort, and Protocol
```

Is it possible for me to determine if this netflow is in forward direction or backward direction ?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "forward or backward", exactly? The field names themselves already indicate the direction (source → destination).

Comment: I believe after the connection is established, it no longer matters which side initiated it. At least with TCP, UDP. Each packet has *its* source and *its* destination.

Answer (score 0):

Netflow records are always unidirectional, that is to say if you have a short conversation between device A and device B you will generate two data records. One record will present stats from A to B, and the other from B to A. Netflow records always assume the flow is going from source to destination.

Determining client/server relationships can sometimes be inferred by port numbers. Determining TCP SYN -> SYNACK -> ACK relationships may not be possible since tcpflags is the cumulative of all flags seen.